# ISC DHCP server - append "01" to the end of Option 43

Tags: isc-dhcp

My current Option 43 generates this hex value in DHCP Offer. See my current configuration below.

```
f2080a0a0a0a0a141414
```

I need to add "01" at its very end and increase length from "08" to "09". The final hex should look like this:

```
f2090a0a0a0a0a14141401
```

Current configuration:

```
option space Cisco_LWAPP_AP;
option Cisco_LWAPP_AP.server-address code 242 = array of ip-address;

# eth0 DHCP scope
subnet 192.168.73.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
interface eth0;
range 192.168.73.100 192.168.73.200;
option routers 192.168.73.1;
option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 1.1.1.1;
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;
vendor-option-space Cisco_LWAPP_AP;
option Cisco_LWAPP_AP.server-address 10.10.10.10, 10.20.20.20;
}
```

---

**Here is the solution using vendor-encapsulated-options, which lets you enter the value direct in hex:**

```
# eth0 DHCP scope on ISC DHCP server
subnet 192.168.130.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
interface eth0;
range 192.168.130.100 192.168.130.200;
option routers 192.168.130.1;
option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 1.1.1.1;
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;
option vendor-encapsulated-options f2:09:0a:0a:0a:0a:0a:14:14:14:01;
}
```

Comment: Found solution and shared above.

Comment: Why is the solution above in the _question_? Nobody will notice it there. Solutions should be posted below as _answers_.